# How do i call nested methods of dependency injected service from a directive's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
function myController($scope,helperService)
  {

   function getFormattedDT() {
      var localDate = "2016-04-04 12:55:55";
      var inputDate = helperService.parsedDate(helperService.formatDate(localDate));
    } 
     getFormattedDT();
   }
```

I am getting the error as  **"TypeError : helperService.formatDate is not a function"**.

```
(function (myApp)
 {
    myApp.service('helperService',['$http','$q','$sce','miscService', function($http,$q,$sce,'miscService') {

    function formatDate(dateTime) {
        return ....
    }

    function parsedDate(date) {
       return ....
     }

}(angular.module('myApp')
```

> But if i keep the function in the myController, then it works well.
>   How do i call nested methods in injected dependencies of angular.

Comment: Post `helperService` code please.

Comment: if the `parsedDate` method is available, I guess ther must be a typo. Could you create a plnkr with your whole code?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski i have updated with the correct error message.

Comment: Having the code of `helperService` would be necessary to be able to analyze deeper. The code you posted is totally valid as is, so the error must be there

Comment: @Hugues Stefanski I have added the helperService code

Comment: formatDate and parsedDate are not put onto the helperService instance. I think you need this.formatDate = function formatDate(dateTime){...} and this.parsedDate = function parsedDate(date) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `helperService` should return an object with the methods on it, something like this:

```
(function (myApp)
  {
    myApp.service('helperService'
     ['$http','$q','$sce','miscService',
      function($http,$q,$sce,'miscService') {

        function formatDate(dateTime) {
          return ....
        }

        function parsedDate(date) {
          return ....
        }

        return{
          parsedDate: parsedDate,
          formatDate: formatDate
        }

  }(angular.module('myApp')
```

The `angular` `service` registration expects a method that returns an object to be used.